# noUislider Trackbar добавить к ползункам отоброжение данных

Tags: javascript, jquery

Как вставить в слайдер noUislider там трекбар с двумя ползунками и хочу к ползункам данные добавить сверху что бы отоброжались. Как это сделать?

```js
var snapSlider = document.getElementById('range-slider');
noUiSlider.create(snapSlider, {
  start: [12, 18],
  snap: true,
  connect: true,
  range: {
    'min': 10,
    '10%': 11,
    '20%': 12,
    '30%': 13,
    '40%': 14,
    '50%': 15,
    '60%': 16,
    '70%': 17,
    '80%': 18,
    '90%': 19,
    'max': 20

  }
});

var snapValues = [
  document.getElementById('slider-value-lower'),
  document.getElementById('slider-value-upper')
];
var timefield = document.getElementById('time');
timefield.value = '12:00 - 18:00';

snapSlider.noUiSlider.on('update', function(values, handle) {
  snapValues[handle].innerHTML = parseInt(values[handle]) + ':00';
  timefield.value = parseInt(values[0]) + ':00 - ' + parseInt(values[1]) + ':00';

});
```

```html
<div id="range-slider"></div>
<span class="slider-values"><span id="slider-value-lower">9:00</span><span> - </span><span id="slider-value-upper">17:00</span></span>
```

Вот тут такие данные на каждом ползунке https://codepen.io/blacklightdesign/pen/GoQbdL?page=1&.