# noUislider range - как вывести данные над каждым ползунком?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Получается есть слайдер noUislider range. 
И там два ползунка что бы время выставлять у меня. Хочу вывести данные над каждым ползунком, но текст не добавляется(я хочу переменные времени вставить при движении - уже есть функция работает, но не вставляется туда текстом почему-то).
Как добавить данные к ползункам?

```js
var snapSlider = document.getElementById('range-slider');
noUiSlider.create(snapSlider, {
  start: [12, 18],
  snap: true,
  connect: true,
  range: {
    'min': 10,
    '10%': 11,
    '20%': 12,
    '30%': 13,
    '40%': 14,
    '50%': 15,
    '60%': 16,
    '70%': 17,
    '80%': 18,
    '90%': 19,
    'max': 20
  }
});

var snapValues = [
  document.getElementById('slider-value-lower'),
  document.getElementById('slider-value-upper')
];
var timefield = document.getElementById('time');
timefield.value = '12:00 - 18:00';

snapSlider.noUiSlider.on('update', function(values, handle) {
  snapValues[handle].innerHTML = parseInt(values[handle]) + ':00';
  timefield.value = parseInt(values[0]) + ':00 - ' + parseInt(values[1]) + ':00';
});
```

http://has-band.ru/checkout/

Comment: покажите код !!!

Comment: tooltips? - https://refreshless.com/nouislider/slider-options/#section-tooltips

Comment: вот код а этот сайт почему не работает у меня (stxdtm)

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [noUislider Trackbar добавить к ползункам отоброжение данных](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/791822/nouislider-trackbar-%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b7%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%bc-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85)

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что это клон вопроса https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/791822/nouislider-trackbar-добавить-к-ползункам-отоброжение-данных

Answer (score 0):

Решение найдено.

Добавил - `tooltips:true`.

Оказалось, что сайт с документацией в Казахстане не работает, извиняюсь что побеспокоил.